# How to apply scrolling according to height of a div?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am facing alignment issue while  height is getting expanded.

Scenario : I have a div tag where I need to apply scrolling if the height of the div will more than the fixed height.For fixed height scrolling will not applicable.

Please help on this.

```css
#configurator .content .white-box {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
  /*overflow:scroll;*/
}
#configurator .content .white-box-accessory {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
#configurator .content .white-box-services {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="white-box">
  <div>
    <p>Accasory Header
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="white-box-accessory">
    <p>
      Accesory 1
      <br>Accesory 2
      <br>Accesory 3
      <br>Accesory 4
      <br>Accesory 5
      <br>Accesory 6
      <br>Accesory 7
      <br>Accesory 8
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Services Header
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="white-box-services">
    <p>
      Services 1
      <br>Services 2
      <br>Services 3
      <br>Services 4
      <br>Services 5
      <br>Services 6
      <br>Services 7
      <br>Services 8
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the SHORTEST code necessary to reproduce IT. Please provide minimum code.

Answer (score 0):

Give **max-height** in the css to the div and **overflow:auto**, so that the scroll will be applied after that height is reached,

```css
#configurator .content .white-box {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
  /*overflow:scroll;*/
}
 .white-box-accessory {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
  max-height:100px;
  overflow:auto;
}
 .white-box-services {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
  max-height:100px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="white-box"> 
        <div>
             <p>Accasory Header
    </p>
        </div>

        <div class="white-box-accessory">    
            <p>
   Accesory 1<br>
   Accesory 2<br>
   Accesory 3<br>
   Accesory 4<br>
   Accesory 5<br>
   Accesory 6<br>
   Accesory 7<br>
   Accesory 8
   </p>
        </div>

        <div>    
         <p>Services Header
   </p>
        </div>

        <div class="white-box-services">    
              <p>
     Services 1<br>
     Services 2<br>
     Services 3<br>
     Services 4<br>
     Services 5<br>
     Services 6<br>
     Services 7<br>
     Services 8
     </p>
        </div>

 </div>
```

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sravanaravind/dxf77bhr/)

Answer (score 0):

First add a CSS class to all divs you want to target. I have used `scroll`. Then add a `max-height` to set the fixed height, then add `overflow-y: auto` to add scrolling when the content is more than the `max-height`.

In the snippet below I have removed some of the services from your code to demonstrate the effect.

```css
.scroll {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="white-box">
  <div>
    <p>Accasory Header
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="white-box-accessory scroll">
    <p>
      Accesory 1
      <br>Accesory 2
      <br>Accesory 3
      <br>Accesory 4
      <br>Accesory 5
      <br>Accesory 6
      <br>Accesory 7
      <br>Accesory 8
    </p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>Services Header
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="white-box-services scroll">
    <p>
      Services 1
      <br>Services 2
      <br>Services 3
      <br>Services 4
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  width: 700px;
}
#header {
  display: table-row;
  height: 30px;
}
#right-col {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 320px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 2px black solid;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#inner-right {
  height: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: ivory;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">Header</div>
  <div id="body">
    <div id="right-col">
      <div id="header-text">Header</div>
      <div id="inner-right">
        <p>
          Accesory 1
          <br>Accesory 2
          <br>Accesory 3
          <br>Accesory 4
          <br>Accesory 5
          <br>Accesory 6
          <br>Accesory 7
          <br>Accesory 8 Accesory 1
          <br>Accesory 2
          <br>Accesory 3
          <br>Accesory 4
          <br>Accesory 5
          <br>Accesory 6
          <br>Accesory 7
          <br>Accesory 8 Accesory 5
          <br>Accesory 6
          <br>Accesory 7
          <br>Accesory 8
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```